# Is it required to use createRecord before creating a new model instance?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

While building my first app with ember and ember-data I've noticed that at one point I started getting the following error when typing in an input field for a newly created model:

> Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('notes', t) to the 'content' property of object proxy : its 'content' is undefined.

I solved this issue by adding the following code to the route:

```
App.LessonNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('lesson');
    } 
});
```

My understanding is that this error started happening when I created (instead of letting ember generate) the LessonController using `ObjectController`.

I'm now wondering:

1. Is it required to use createRecord before creating a new model instance?
2. Is this the best way of preventing this error from happening?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, Your approach is good.

In order to *use* a model in a view, you have to have the model instance available somehow. So if you try to use `content` when nothing has been assigned to it, it will fail. I go around that with a different approach, but creating the record within an action handler.

For some scenarios, specially with small models, I generally create corresponding properties in the controller (sort of a viewModel approach) with an action to handle the save. Then I actually create the record in that action, passing the controller properties arguments of `createRecord`.

Example (totally conceptual):

```
...

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});

...  

App.PersonAddController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

    personName: null,

    actions: {
        save: function() {

            var theName = this.get('personName');

            var person = this.store.createRecord('person', {name: theName});

            person.save().then(
                 ...pointers to success and failure handlers go here...
            ).done(
                 ...transition goes here...     
            );

        }, 
        cancel: function {
            this.set('personName', null);
        }
    }

})
```

Then in the template, I bind the input to the controller prop rather than a model.

```
{{input type="text" value=controller.personName}}
```

With this approach, my `Route#model` doesn't output a blank model to be added to my store, so I don't have to deal with `rollback` or anything.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll try to implement that to see which one suits me better. However while trying it seems I cannot use the done handler on model.save, it's always throwing this error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function `